# Building `bookdown` book in 1-up level directory

Tags: r, stringr, bookdown

**Background -**
My entire `bookdown` project is in `_source` directory, and I wanted to have the compiled book in the 1-up directory in `docs`.
The full path is - `"C:/Users/kbc/project1/docs/_source"`

**Working solution -**
I am able to do this by hardcoding the output directory in `_bookdown.yml` using -
`output_dir: 'C:/Users/kbc/project1/docs'`

**Issue -**
However, I wanted to be flexible with paths by using `here::here()` to retrieve the present location and strip the last `/_source` part using -
`output_dir: stringr::str_remove_all(here::here(), "/_source")`.

But the build fails with following error -

```
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... write_ref_keys -> <Anonymous> -> writeLines -> file
In addition: There were 32 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

Why `output_dir:` accepts the hardcoded character array, but not the character array from the function? What can I do for the flexible-approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can just use `output_dir: ../` (the trailing slash is optional). The two dots `../` means exactly what you were looking for, and you don't need to rely on two additional packages (**here** and **stringr**).

That said, I don't recommend this directory structure, because the source is contained in the output directory. I'd recommend separating the source from the output directory, so that the output directory contains purely output, otherwise you might accidentally delete the full source when cleaning up the output directory (e.g., running `bookdown::clean_book()`). You may consider putting the source under `C:/Users/kbc/project1/Rmd`, and set `output_dir: ../docs/`.

Comment: Thanks @Yihui Xie, for the solution. I also liked your recommendation of separating the source from output. Now, I'm using `docs-source` for source, and `docs` for output for the documentation of my code in GitHub repo. Again, thanks for the kind help. Also, I'm a big fan of your work and your commitment to open-source projects is highly appreciative. :)